# how to display future date in datetimepicker in windows application?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am creating an windows application in that i used two forms.First form contain first datetimepicker and in second form contain  second datetimepicker .If i am select any date in first datetimepicker then in second datetimepicker display future date which is 6 month differences.following is example

if i select date in first datetimepicker i.e. 8/9/2012 (mm:dd:yyy) then

in second datetimepicker display date i.e. 2/8/2013(mm:dd:yyy) there is must 6 month difference in second datetimepicker. .

Comment: Have you seen `DateTimePicker.Value` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

On second read-through of your question, I now see you have two different forms. You will need to expose the `DateTimePicker.ValueChanged` event in the first form, and then expose the `DateTimePicker.Value` property in the second form. For example:

```
class DateEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DateTime Date {get; private set;}

    public DateEventArgs(DateTime d) 
        : base()
    {
        this.Date = d;
    }
}

class FirstForm : Form
{
    DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();

    public event EventHandler<DateEventArgs> DateSelected;
    protected virtual void OnDateSelected(DateEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DateEventArgs> handler = DateSelected;
        if(handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    public FirstForm()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(dtp);
        dtp.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(dtp_ValueChanged);
    }

    void dtp_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateEventArgs dea = new DateEventArgs(dtp.Value.Date);
        OnDateSelected(dea);
    }
}

class SecondForm : Form
{
    DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();

    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        set { dtp.Value = value; }
    }

    public SecondForm()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(dtp);
    }
}

static class Controller
{
    FirstForm f1;
    SecondForm f2;

    static void Go()
    {
        f1 = new FirstForm();
        f2 = new SecondForm();
        f1.DateSelected += new EventHandler<DateEventArgs>(f1_DateSelected);

        f1.Show();
        f2.Show();
    }

    static void f1_DateSelected(object sender, DateEventArgs e)
    {
        f2.SelectedDate = e.Date.AddMonths(6);
    }
}
```

Comment: it show me error on += invalid token and method have return type on  new  EventHandler. and how can call this method on second form?

Comment: i have first datetimepicker on first form and second datetimepicker on second form.

Comment: Yes I realized this and updated my answer. It is untested, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what you have to do.

Comment: but my datetimepicker name is firstdatetimepicker and seconddatetimepicker. i am new in programming please explain correctly where need to write this code

Comment: @Maddy No offense intended, but this is probably not a good problem to start learning with. I suggest you take a step back and first learn about exposing properties of a class, then learn about raising and handling events. Then come back to this problem and try to understand what this code is doing. I believe I have written it rather simply, but I will remove the lambda in adding an event handler to `f1.DateSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

this should help

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize picker 
        dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(ObjectForValue1).AddMonths(6);
    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set title bar to selected date.
        DateTime result = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        this.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: i haved datetimepicker in two different form so  how can access datetimepicker control

Comment: in web app, you can use session, similar store the data in some kind of object for caching.